# Strange roughness feeling on electrically ungrounded surfaces

Tags: electricity, conductors

When I have a device or a surface (typically metallic) that are not well connected to ground I feel a strange feeling when I pass (gently rub) my hand on them. Like the roughness of the surface is different.

I only feel it when I move my hand over the surface and not when it is still.
I tested this with AC or DC currents, and I can feel it in both cases.

I know it has to be with charges accumulation at the surface (call it electrostatic charge), as expected from a conductive material, but I cannot see why exactly I feel that strange feeling while rubbing my hand and not when it's still.

Can it be related to something like an "electron drag force"? Or is there more into it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2824/. Having said that, IMHO the explanations therein lack a scientific basis. It's people guessing what may be happening.